# Relation between the solution of two systems of partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider a smooth annular (open and bonded) domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\Gamma_i$ and $\Gamma_o$ be its interior and exterior boundary, respectively. Denote the outward normal vector to $\Gamma_o$ by $\nu$. Now, suppose that $-\Delta u_j = 0$ in $\Omega$ and $\nabla u_j \cdot \nu = -1$ on $\Gamma_o$. Also, let $u_j = j \geqslant 0$ ($j$ is fixed constant) on $\Gamma_i$. How does the solution to the case $j=0$ relate to the solution of the problem when $j=1$. More precisely, is it possible to write the solution of the first case in terms of the second one? Say, something like $u_0 = -c u_1$, where $c \in \mathbb{R}$?